# Taking element screenshots in a loop. Detecting and skipping hidden web elements. Using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, puppeteer

I am taking screenshots of 'strip' elements on a webpage. Im having trouble detecting elements that are not currently displayed on the site.

I am taking screenshots of all the desktop elements on a website.
What I have tried is using `await page.$$eval('section .strip', p => p.map((e) => e.getAttribute('display')))`
Im also aware that I could use `getcomputedstyles()` but dont understand where to add this with regards to map().

```js
let arr = await await page.$$('section .strip');
let naming = await page.$$eval('section .strip', p => p.map((e) => e.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('id')))

for(el in arr){
    await arr[el].screenshot({path: './' +naming[el] + '.png'})
}
```

I expect a screenshot to be taken if the element is there and ignored if the element is visible (display: hidden).

What i am getting is, When using `element.screenshot()` Im getting and error of `(node:3736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not simply ignore the element if the element does not exist. It [throws an error](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/5ee21d97e796263857b9f3fbeaf63366179d346f/lib/JSHandle.js#L353) as you are experiencing.

**Solution**

As the code (see link about) is already checking if the element has a bounding box, you do not need to check this yourself. Instead, you can ignore the error by wrapping the expression in a `try..catch` like this:

```js
for(el in arr){
  try {
    await arr[el].screenshot({path: './' +naming[el] + '.png'})
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`No screenshot for ${naming[el]}: ${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

This will try to take screenshot of all elements and log the elements for which this was not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I’d been looking at the element itself and determining its characteristic. A try catch allows it to ignore and log issues if shots are not taken.